# Solve equation $x^i=i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equation?
It is not $x=i^{\frac{1}{i}}$.

Wolframalpha says it is $x=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$.

But how?

Comment: convert to [Euler formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) or take log on both sides and solve

Comment: $e^{\pi/2}$ is one of the values of $i^{1/i}.$ Hy do you say it isn't $i^{1/i}?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is one of the values. How to make $i^{\frac{1}{i}}$ $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write $$x=e^{\ln x}$$ and $$i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}\cdot 1$$ The $1$ is to allow for any other complex solutions. $$1=e^{i2\pi n}$$
Then $$e^{i\ln x}=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n)}\\\ln x=\frac\pi2+2\pi n$$

$$x=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$$

Comment: You added an $i$ in the last line that shouldn't be there. It should be $e^{\frac\pi2+2\pi n}.$

Comment: Oh, I see that error was an addition by @ayan.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My bad, fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You need a number that when raised to $i$ gives you $i$. And if you know Euler Formula you may remember that:
$$ e^{i0} = 1 $$
$$ e^{i\pi / 2} = i $$
$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 $$
$$ e^{i3\pi/2} = - i $$

But then, you know that for any arbitrary $x$, $e^{ix} = e^{i(x+2\pi)} = e^{i(x + 4\pi)}$ and so on, because $2\pi$ is a full turn. So you can write:
$$ e^{i(0+2n\pi)} = 1 $$
$$ e^{i(\pi / 2+2n\pi)} = i $$
$$ e^{i(\pi+2n\pi)} = -1 $$
$$ e^{i(3\pi/2+2n\pi)} = - i $$

with $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$

So, you replace $i$ by $e^{i(\pi / 2+2n\pi)}$ and then it should be straighforward to solve the equation.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Well it is $i^\frac 1i$, just remember that complex exponential are multivalued.

$i^\frac 1i=i^{-i}=\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}+2in\pi}\right)^{-i}=e^{-i^2\frac{\pi}2-2i^2n\pi}=e^{\frac{\pi}2+2n\pi}\ $ for $\ n\in\mathbb Z$